# How do I create a product order summary table using EE addons?

Tags: add-on, relationships

I have two channels, one called Product System (product_system) and one called Product Orders (product_orders). The product system contains all the products that the company produces and the product orders contains all the products ordered in a particular order. The two channels are linked by product_id relationship field in product_orders.

What I want to be able to do is to produce a product order spreadsheet, that allows me to show the orders in rows, the products in columns and the number of products ordered, in a particular order, in the related square in the grid.

The columns must be dynamic, so that if a new product is added, it automatically appears in the grid.

Comment: Are you using a relationship fieldtype to relate products to orders? Or is it just a text field?

Comment: I would recommend that you rewrite this so that the question is explicit in the body of the question, and that you provide more details such as whether you are trying to display this data in the control panel or in a template.

Comment: Also, post what you've already tried.

Comment: You should be able to do this with the query module a template (and maybe some PHP) but you'll need some SQL chops to write a query to stitch the data together.

I suspect you're using EE2.x but if not I wrote a simple 'Reports' module for EE1.x which allows you to provide clients with a nice front end for SQL query based reports - it can also handle post processing on a query before serving up a CSV (https://github.com/ninefour/reports.mod.ee_addon).

Comment: I wrote up a possible solution to this (Looping Through All Channel Fields) at http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/5711/293